# How to add substring to some (not all) fasta headers

Tags: shell, perl, awk, sed, fasta

I have a fasta file that looks like this:

```
>miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34108_3p  Parhyale hawaiensis 34108_3p 
AATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTGC
>miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34106_3p  Parhyale hawaiensis 34106_3p 
AATTGCACTGATCCCGGCCTGC
>LQNS02136402.1_14821_5p  Parhyale hawaiensis 14821_5p 
CCGTAAGGCCGAAGACAAGAA
>LQNS02278094.1_35771_5p  Parhyale hawaiensis 35771_5p 
AAGAATAAGCCCGAGCAAGTCGAT
```

I want to change the headers to make them look like this:

```
>miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34108_3p  Parhyale hawaiensis 34108_3p 
AATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTGC
>miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34106_3p  Parhyale hawaiensis 34106_3p 
AATTGCACTGATCCCGGCCTGC
>miR-LQNS02136402.1_14821_5p  Parhyale hawaiensis 14821_5p 
CCGTAAGGCCGAAGACAAGAA
>miR-LQNS02278094.1_35771_5p  Parhyale hawaiensis 35771_5p 
AAGAATAAGCCCGAGCAAGTCGAT
```

Note that not all the headers changed, just the last 2 in the example, where the word "miRs" was added.
So far I have been doing this like this:
`perl -p -e "s/^>/>miR-/g" seq.fasta`
But this will end up with some IDs having miR- added even though they already had it.

I know I can subset the file and apply this to just the ones missing the miR- at the beginning and then remerge but I would like to find an easier way to do it in one line without much manual intervention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can to negative lookahead to only match the  lines starting with `>` but not followed by `miR-`. Notice the single quotes.

```
perl -p -e 's/^>(?!miR-)/>miR-/g' file
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also say with `sed`:

```
sed -E "s/^>(miR-)?/>miR-/" seq.fasta
```

Answer (score 0):

with `awk` you can get the records that don't have `miR`:

```
awk '$0 !~ /miR-/ && $0 ~ /^>/'  file
>LQNS02136402.1_14821_5p  Parhyale hawaiensis 14821_5p
>LQNS02278094.1_35771_5p  Parhyale hawaiensis 35771_5p
```

and then put `miR` only in those records:

```
awk '$0 !~ /miR-/ && $0 ~ /^>/ {gsub(/^>/, ">miR-")} 1' file
>miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34108_3p  Parhyale hawaiensis 34108_3p
AATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTGC
>miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34106_3p  Parhyale hawaiensis 34106_3p
AATTGCACTGATCCCGGCCTGC
>miR-LQNS02136402.1_14821_5p  Parhyale hawaiensis 14821_5p
CCGTAAGGCCGAAGACAAGAA
>miR-LQNS02278094.1_35771_5p  Parhyale hawaiensis 35771_5p
AAGAATAAGCCCGAGCAAGTCGA
```